# swift tableview динамическое содержимое ячейки

Tags: swift, tableview

Суть такова : в зависимости от входных данных в ячейку (`cell`) `tableview` должны добавляться `1...n` кнопнок, при нажатии на кнопки вызывается одна и та же функция, но с разными аргументами (зависит от кнопки), в разных ячейках будет разное кол-во кнопок

т.е пришел массив, где указано кол-во ячеек, сколько кнопок для каждой ячейки и аргументы под каждую кнопку

Подскажите, как такое реализовать ? Проблема в том, что в разных ячейках может быть разное кол-во кнопок - это ставит меня в тупик, получается, что еще разные действия под разные кнопки будут и заранее их программно прописать не смогу. Ни в коем случае не прошу писать код за меня, лишь подсказать идею, как такое сделать или правильную замену данной задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну смотри, допустим у тебя в первой ячейки стоит какой-нибудь UITextField, от которого зависит количество кнопок.

Допустим, если внутрь этого UITextField вписали цифру 8 - тебе нужно показать 8 кнопок.

Отсюда, делаем следующее.

(Писать буду по MVC, в одном классе, чтобы ты понял идею)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var selectedCountOfButtons = 0
    var tableView: UITableView!
    //...
    func textFieldTextChanged(sender: UITextField) {

        // Здесь мы тригерим смену текста у твоей первой ячейки
        guard let count = Int(sender.text ?? "") else {
            return
        }
        self.update(count: count)
    }

    private func update(count: Int) {
        self.selectedCountOfButtons = count
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func buttonClicked() {
        // здесь можешь тригерить какой именно button нажат, например, задав ему button.tag = indexPath.row
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0: // вернуть статичную ячейку с текстом
        default: // вернуть кнопку с таргетом
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1 + selectedCountOfButtons
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не могли ли бы вы немного по подробнее рассказать об "вернуть кнопку с таргетом" ? Мне нужно получить саму ячейку (`dequeueReusableCell`), создать `n` кнопок и потом сделать `cell.addSubview(кнопка)` (что бы добавить несколько кнопок - мне нужно в цикле создавать кнопку и добавлять ? ) ? я правильно понял ?

Comment: А зачем вам добавлять много кнопок в одной ячейке, если можно добавлять новые ячейки с одной кнопкой?

Comment: в данном случае, мне как раз нужно несколько кнопок в одной ячейке, сделал через cell.addSubview, вроде бы, все работает, спасибо